# Trouble Creating New Column in Pandas, int and str

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column in my data frame but keep getting this error message:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

The datatypes are 'object' for both columns. I attempted to do this first:

```
ops['Plan ID'] = ops['Plan ID'].astype(str)
```

and

```
ops['Client Name'] = ops['Client Name'].astype(str)
```

and do this to create a new column:

```
ops['new'] = ops['Plan ID'] + ops['Client Name']
```

But I'm still receiving that error message.

Here are the columns

```
Plan ID   Client Name
---------------------
1          Jack
2          John
3          Bob
4          Mark
```

Here is what I want the new column to be:

```
1Jack
2John
3Bob
4Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the original columns, I did it using

```py
df['new_col'] =df['Plan ID'].astype(str).str.rstrip('0').str.rstrip('.') + df['Client Name']
```

Example:

I introduced a non-int ID do demonstrate the robustness of this method. I assumed that `Client Name` will always contain strings.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Plan ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5.5], 
                   'Client Name': ['Jack', 'John', 'Bob', 'Mark', 'Helen']})

# setting object type to match the question
df['Plan ID'] = df['Plan ID'].astype('object')
df['Client Name'] = df['Client Name'].astype('object')
df['new_col'] =df['Plan ID'].astype(str).str.rstrip('0').str.rstrip('.') + df['Client Name']

df['new_col']

    new_col
0   1Jack
1   2John
2   3Bob
3   4Mark
4   5.5Helen
```

Comment: If you downvoted, please tell me why, or provide data showing problem with this answer. Data provided in the question are not triggering any error to me

Comment: I did not downvote. I still don't get why the OP's code throws that error. might be something weird in the data frame. What you have introduce more issues than there are?

Comment: I said "you" to the person who actually downvoted. I assumed there is a problem with formatting in  some `Plan ID` values. Is this code working now ?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use str.cat instead of simply adding the two columns together. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html

Something like the following should do the trick.

```py
ops['new'] = ops['Plan ID'].str.cat([ops['Client Name']])
```